# Can I search a string for character (X OR Y) in C?

Tags: c, search, strstr

I'm trying to search a string for a character to find its position in the string, however, the character can be one of three.

I'm trying to achieve the equivalent of this:

```
char *foo = strstr(string, x);
```

where x can be either "i," "j," or "k."

What would be the best way of going about this?

Answer (score 7):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char *string = "I'm trying to search a string";
    char *x = "ijk";
    char *foo = strpbrk(string, x);
    if(foo)
        printf("%c at %d\n", *foo, foo - string);//zero origin
    else
        puts("not found");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [`strcspn()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strspn.3.html) function,

```
char *foo = string + strcspn(string, "ijk");
```

and if you only want the position, then just

```
size_t position = strcspn(string, "ijk");
```

this is a sample implementation of how to use it in this case

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char *findany(const char *const haystack, const char *const needle)
{
    size_t skip;

    if (haystack == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if (needle == NULL)
        return haystack;

    skip = strcspn(haystack, needle);
    if (*(haystack + skip) == '\0')
        return NULL;

    return haystack + skip;
}

int main(void)
{
    const char *string = "xksjadueaailkik";
    const char *found;

    found = string;
    while ((found = findany(found, "ijk")) != NULL)
        printf("%s\n", found++);

    return 0;
}
return 0;
```

**ouput**:

```
ksjadueaailkik
jadueaailkik
ilkik
kik
ik
k
```

this makes the `findany()` function similar to `strchr()` but it takes a set of characters instead of a single one.

**Note**: I just noticed that this is the reinvention of `strpbrk()` so that's the right solution i.e. **BLUEPIXY**'s answer.

Comment: New to me. Just asking, does this fulfill the requirement of `either "i," "j," or "k."`?

Comment: strcspn return size of a substring from first char to the first occurrence of "ijk". Sourav is asching for the poiner to the firt occurence.

Comment: @LPs it's still useful in this case.